# Speed up mongo queries by parallel them and use a ThreadPool?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, threadpool, connection-pooling

Our mongodb architecture stores data weekly. Every week has it's own db with the same collection set. Sometimes I have to check data up to over 12 weeks that means I run the same query over 12 different databases (all on one mongo server):

```
...
for (MongoOperationDto week : allWeeks) {
  results.addAll(repo.find(gid, week.db(), week.collection());
}
...
```

In this case I run sequentially 12 time find(). I guess the internal connection pool handle them or? If not would it be a benefit if I create 12 Java threads and every thread would run one find? Maybe like:

```
public class FindTask {

    @Autowired
    MyMongoRepo repo;

    @Async
    public List<Result> doFindTask(long gid, MongoOperationDto week) {
         return repo.find(gid, week.db(), week.connection());
    }
}
```

Which approach is actually faster or is there no speed difference in retrieving the data?

Comment: Test it to find out. Keep in mind that even if you have 12 threads on Java side performing `find()`, they're still using the same server (however this does not mean there wouldn't be a performance difference). Connection pooling is not related to this *at all*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) handle the connections, nothing more:

> In software engineering, a connection pool is a cache of database connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the database are required

For your first code, It means that after the first find has been finished instead of establishing a new connection to MongoDB it can reuse an existing already opened and not used connection present in the pool.

So in the first case, you will have 12 serial queries and 1 connection used for each query.

In the second case, you have 12 parallel queries using at the same time 12 different connections.

In terms of performances if the queries need a long time the second solution should be faster (time to complete), but it uses more resources (ram, cpu time). Note that the time is also influenced by your MongoDB architecture. If your queries operate with long disk operations on the same disk probably parallelizing them don't improve too much the total time.

Comment: your answer is complete! I just want to emphasis on thread creation overhead which is too much! so if your have bunch of small queries or a normal server, don't do this at all!

Comment: Thread overhead is not significant when invoking an external database. But the code can be a lot more difficult to mantain so if the performance are not affected it is a good idea to not try this way.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. And I am aware of that with threading I create some overhead and consume more RAM/ CPU resources.

Comment: @Grimbo you are true, you use more ram and cpu, but both are minimal considering time of accessing disk (as a database do), accessing the network (to move data from the java program to mongodb and viceversa) and memory usage (that is minimal considering data returned from the database).

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I'm not talking about overhead on java side!
overhead in mongo server is beyond significant!

Comment: @Mohsen89z On the Mongo side I already said *"Note that the time is also influenced by your mongodb architecture. If your queries operates with long disk operations on the same disk probably parallelizing them don't improve too much the total time."*. As I said it depends on the architecture because if MongoDb is distributed between different nodes and the queries operates on different disks parallelizing them can be an improuvement.

Comment: yep and I was emphasising on this point! saw lots of people destroy their mongod only by creating a new thread or connection for each query!